# Can't press certain keyboard keys together

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just purchased a new gaming keyboard (Genesis Natec RX66). When I play FPS games (for example CS:GO), I can't press **Left Shift+A+4** at the same time but Left Shift+A+3 or Left Shift+A+2 etc works just fine. Also if I press *Right Shift+A+4* works as well. So the only problem is with the combination **Left Shift+A+4** . Is there any way to get around this problem? I know its not the best gaming keyboard but I think its a decent one that shouldn't have any limitations to such things.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, " I can't press Left Shift+A+4 at the same time"?  They won't go down or nothing (that you expect) happens.  Could it be that that combination is being caught by some other program.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately keyboards might be - and most often are - [build in a way limiting detection of keys pressed simultaneously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29). Natec don't specify Genesis RX66 rollover so it's probably isn't great.

Comment: If it detects the other combinations of the same length, it is not likely a rollover problem.